# Why am I getting a "NameError: name 'database' is not defined", even if I am defining main?

Tags: python, nameerror, traceback

When I try and run my code I am getting a Name Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "dna.py", line 24, in <module>
    main ()
  File "dna.py", line 15, in main
    STR_searcher()
  File "dna.py", line 19, in STR_searcher
    STR_dict = dict.fromkeys(range(1, len(database.fieldnames)))
NameError: name 'database' is not defined
```

When I put the helper function on top, the program worked but I am planning on using a few more functions so I want to put them at the bottom and define the first one as main. I also tried using `if __name__ == "__main__": main()`, but that didn't work either. So how can I have my other functions be put below main while ensuring that everything is defined?

```
from sys import argv, exit
import csv
from collections import OrderedDict

def main():
    if len(argv) != 3:
        print("Usage: python dna.py data.csv sequence.txt")
        exit(1)
    
with open(argv[1]) as csv_file: 
    database = csv.DictReader(csv_file)

    with open(argv[2]) as txt_file: 
        sequence = txt_file.read()
        STR_searcher()
                    
        
def STR_searcher():
    STR_dict = dict.fromkeys(range(1, len(database.fieldnames)))
    for i in range(len(STR_dict)):
        for j in range(len(sequence)):
            print("hello")        
            
main ()
```

Comment: I don't think I understand why you expect the `database` value created in `main` to be usable inside `STR_searcher`. Are you also expecting `csv_file` and `txt_file` to be usable there?

Comment: "So how can I have my other functions be put below main while ensuring that everything is defined?" It seems that you think the problem is caused by defining `main()` before `STR_searcher`? This is not correct.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel I started coding 3 wks ago and started using python 3 days ago, so I am honestly pretty confused overall. I was using C before so I was used to defining my variables ahead of using them, and my program worked when the `STR_searcher` function was above the rest of the program, so that is why is seemed like that was the problem to me.

Comment: What you are trying to do would not work in C either, regardless of the order you put the functions in. I think you may also have misunderstood how "defining your variables" works in C. The general concept you need to understand here is *variable scope*.

Answer (score 1):

It is because in the function scope of `STR_searcher()` the variable `database` is not defined. To give the variable to the function, defined it as:
`def STR_searcher(database):` and call it from the `main` function like `STR_searcher(database)`.

Answer (score 0):

This happens because your `database` variable is defined in the context of your `main` function and inside `STR_searcher` it's as if it doesn't exist. Consider moving this to a class, example:

```
def MyClass(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.database =None
        self.sequence=None
    
    def main(self):
        if len(argv) != 3:
            print("Usage: python dna.py data.csv sequence.txt")
            exit(1)
            
        with open(argv[1]) as csv_file: 
            self.database = csv.DictReader(csv_file)
        
            with open(argv[2]) as txt_file: 
                self.sequence = txt_file.read()
                self.STR_searcher()
                        
            
    def STR_searcher(self):
        STR_dict = dict.fromkeys(range(1, len(self.database.fieldnames)))
        for i in range(len(STR_dict)):
            for j in range(len(self.sequence)):
                print("hello")
```

You could then run it by doing:

```
Myclass().main()
```

Answer (score 0):

You should pass the variables to the function

```
from collections import OrderedDict
from sys import argv, exit
import csv

def main():
    if len(argv) != 3:
        print("Usage: python dna.py data.csv sequence.txt")
        exit(1)

    with open(argv[1]) as csv_file: 
        database = csv.DictReader(csv_file)

    with open(argv[2]) as txt_file: 
        sequence = txt_file.read()
    
    STR_searcher(database, sequence)
        
def STR_searcher(database, sequence):
    STR_dict = dict.fromkeys(range(1, len(database.fieldnames)))
    for i in range(len(STR_dict)):
        for j in range(len(sequence)):
            print("hello")        
            
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Or you can use `global` keyword however this is not a great way to do it.

```
from collections import OrderedDict
from sys import argv, exit
import csv

database = None
sequence = None

def main():
    global database
    global sequence

    if len(argv) != 3:
        print("Usage: python dna.py data.csv sequence.txt")
        exit(1)

    with open(argv[1]) as csv_file: 
        database = csv.DictReader(csv_file)

    with open(argv[2]) as txt_file: 
        sequence = txt_file.read()
    
    STR_searcher()
           
def STR_searcher():
    global database
    global sequence
    
    STR_dict = dict.fromkeys(range(1, len(database.fieldnames)))
    for i in range(len(STR_dict)):
        for j in range(len(sequence)):
            print("hello")        
            
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```